# Avoid showing error messages while getting the value from TForm.getValue()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tcomb-form-native

I have 2 textboxes

- Email
- Password

I want to disable the button until the user enters valid email and password. So, in the onChange method, I retrieve the value from `form.getValue()` which triggers validation as stated in the docs. If the value is `null`, I change the button's disabled state to `true` else `false`. I only want to show errors when the input loses focus or on submit and not on each `getValue()` call.

As soon as `onChange` is triggered, the form starts showing error in all the fields because I call `form.getValue()`. I want to show the error only when the user moves to the next textbox (focus is lost from the current one) or if the user hits Submit. I don't wanna pester him with error messages when the user just starts typing in the textbox.

**Steps to reproduce**

- Create 2 form fields (email and password with refinements) with
  option containing error messages
- Retrieve the value in the onChange method
- You'll start seeing error messages.

**Code**

```
// @flow
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Platform, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import t from 'tcomb-form-native';
import { resetTo } from 'src/lib/navigation';
import { SIGNED_IN } from 'src/routes/constants';
import { getErrorMessage } from 'src/lib/auth-helpers';
import { FullScreenBGImage } from 'src/components';
import { text, background } from 'src/styles/';
import LoginBG from '../../../assets/images/login-bg.jpg';
import styles from './style';

type Props = {
  loggedIn: boolean,
  navigation: Object,
  login: (string, string) => void,
  user: Object,
};

type States = {
  isDisabled: boolean,
  value: ?Object,
};

const Email = t.refinement(t.String, email => {
  const reg = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
  return reg.test(email);
});

const { Form } = t.form;

// here we define our domain model
const LoginForm = t.struct({
  email: Email,
  password: t.String,
});

const textboxStyle = {
  color: text.color2,
  backgroundColor: background.color1,
  fontSize: 17,
  height: 50,
  paddingVertical: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 7 : 0,
  paddingHorizontal: 16,
  borderWidth: 1,
  marginBottom: 5,
};

const formStylesheet = {
  ...Form.stylesheet,
  textbox: {
    normal: {
      ...textboxStyle,
    },
    error: {
      ...textboxStyle,
    },
  },
  errorBlock: {
    color: text.error,
  },
};

const formOptions = {
  auto: 'placeholders',
  fields: {
   email: { error: 'Enter valid email' },
    password: {
      error: 'Enter valid password'
      password: true,
      secureTextEntry: true,
    },
  },
  stylesheet: formStylesheet,
};

class Login extends PureComponent<Props, States> {
  loginForm: ?Object;
  onFormChange: () => void;

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.loginForm = {};

    this.state = {
      value: null,
      isDisabled: true,
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onFormChange = this.onFormChange.bind(this);
  }

  /**
   * ComponentWillReceiveProps.
   *
   * Redirect if user is logged in
   */
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Props) {
    if (nextProps.loggedIn !== this.props.loggedIn && nextProps.loggedIn) {
      resetTo(SIGNED_IN, nextProps.navigation);
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    // use that ref to get the form value
    const value = this.loginForm ? this.loginForm.getValue() : null;

    if (value) {
      this.props.login(value.email, value.password);
    }
  }

  onFormChange() {
    const value = this.loginForm ? this.loginForm.getValue() : null;

    if (value) {
      this.setState({
        value,
        isDisabled: false,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const errorMessage = getErrorMessage(this.props.user);
    const error = errorMessage
      ? <View><Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{errorMessage}</Text></View>
      : null;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FullScreenBGImage imageSrc={LoginBG} styles={styles.bgImage}>
          <View style={styles.logo}>
            <Text style={styles.logoLabel}>VERUS</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.loginForm}>
            {error}
            <Form
              ref={c => { this.loginForm = c; }}
              type={LoginForm}
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.onFormChange}
              options={formOptions} // pass the options via props
            />

            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={this.handleSubmit}
              underlayColor="#99d9f4"
              disabled={this.state.isDisabled}
            >
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </FullScreenBGImage>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

**Version**

tcomb-form-native v0.6.11

Comment: I think you should place `const errorMessage = getErrorMessage(this.props.user);` into `handleSubmit ` function and set an error state which use to render.

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy It's not related to the form at all. That `errorMessage` is generated on the basis of errors retrieved from server.

Comment: Yes, but it always re-render when you change the form and `errorMessage` isn't `null`, so I just suggest you move it to other function like `onSubmit` and set it to state when you submit btw.

Answer (score 0):

Hey passing by the method will always validate the form first so you should just change the method of onChange and get the value of the email field you want by using something like `this.refs.loginForm.refs.input.refs.email.state.value` where email is the name of your field and loginForm the name of the ref of your form. Then you can test the value with your regex by your own to change the state of the button ;)

Some docs that gave me the idea :
Here : https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form/issues/370

and here https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form/blob/master/GUIDE.md#accessing-fields

Comment: I already knew about this approach. But, I thought maybe there might be a better way. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: No problem ;) if there is another I would love to hear it too :)